# How to implement a Linq query by converting entities to DTOs?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

There are 3 entities, let's say they are presented in this way:

```
**1 - entity**
class A
int id ;
int Name;

[Foreign key]
int id_B;

List C;


**2 - entity**
class B
int id ;
int Name;

List A;

**3 - entity**
class C
int id;
int Name;

[Foreign Key]
int id_A;
```

created an entity DTO (Everything is the same only without foreign keys)

```
1 
class ADTO
int id ;
int Name;
List C;


2 
class BDTO
int id ;
int Name;
List A;

3 
class CDTO
int id;
int Name;
```

Now the request looks like this:

```
var quer = (await _context.A
                                    .Include(b => b.B)
                                        .Include(c => c.C)
                                              .Where(u => u.Id == 1).ToListAsync())
                                                .Select(a => new ADto
                                                {
                                                    Id = a.Id,
                                                  //How to get information about entity B here by converting to DTO                                                   
                                                    C = a.C.Select(cdto => new CDTO{ Id = cdto.Id, Name = cdto.Name}).ToList(),

                                                });
```

How to get information about entity B here by converting to DTO?

Comment: One word: Automapper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are querying "A" as your top-level entity then I believe you're just missing a navigation property to it's associated "B". (As it contains the B_Id FK)

**1 - entity**

```
public class A
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("B")]
    public int id_B { get; set; } 

    public virtual B B { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<C> Cs { get; set;} = new List<C>();
}
```

Then when you project your Entities to DTOs using `Select`:

```
var query = (await _context.A
   .Where(a => a.Id == 1)
   .Select(a => new ADto
   {
       Id = a.Id,
       B = new BDTO { Id = a.B.Id /* ... */ },
       Cs = a.Cs.Select(c => new CDTO{ Id = c.Id, Name = c.Name}).ToList(),
   }).Single();
```

Note that when using `.Select` you do not need to use `.Include` to reference related entities, that is only used to eager load related entities where you want to return an entity graph. (Such as when reading the entities to update values *from* DTOs)  Also, be wary of using any `ToList` operations prior to using a `Select` as this will load entities into memory before applying things like filters, and negates the optimization of queries to fill just what `Select` needs.
});

Comment: Thx, but i have navigation property in my clas A. If i use: B = new BDTO { Id = a.B.Id /* ... */ }, i convert my BDTO in B .... it is not right.

Comment: I did it. Thx )

Answer (score 0):

Normally, I would suggest you implement an interface, that is provided on the constructor of the resulting object

so:

```
public interface IDbOjbect{
   int Id {get;set;}
   string Name{get;set;}
}
```

and then on your DTO object

```
public Class DtoObject {
    public DtoOjbect(IDbOjbect source)
    {
        //Mapping done here.
    }

}
```

Because then you can implement the interface on any persistence layer object, and the mapping will still work.

Because then the linq query is simply:

```
DbOjbectList.Select(x => new DtoObject(x));
```

provided DtoOjbect implements the interface.

your C would look like this:

```
public partial class C {
   public int id {get;set;}
   public string Name {get;set;}  
}

public partial class C : IDbOjbect {
   
}
```

and your CDTO would look like:

```
public Class CDTO{

 public int Id {get;set;}
 public string Name {get;set;}

        public CDTO(IDbOjbect source)
        {
            Id = source.Id;
            Name = source.name;
        }
    }
```

Want to be able to make a DTO from B?

Implement IDbOjbect  on your B

by using

```
public partial class B {
       public int id {get;set;}
       public string Name {get;set;}  
    }

    public partial class B : IDbOjbect {
       
    }
```

and now any C or B can be made into a CDTO.

Best part is, you can make a generic method for your B and C, use the "Where" keyword after you generic definition, and then use the Interface as the type, now you can make a single method that does the same thing based on what has the interface implementation, and this will also work for A, if you implement the interface on A.

Without further modification.

So now that you are asking questions, you original question doesn't, lets expand.

Lets say you have a ResumeInfo Object that only B has available.

You then use the NullPointer pattern together with interface segregation principle.

So you create an interface on your resumeInfo class

Example:

```
public interface IResumeInfo
{
    string PlaceOfEmployment {get;set;}
    DateTime StartOfEmployment {get;set;}
    DateTime? EndOfEmployment {get;set;}

}
```

Then on your ResumeInfo Object:

```
public partial class ResumeInfo
{
        string PlaceOfEmployment {get;set;}
        DateTime StartOfEmployment {get;set;}
        DateTime? EndOfEmployment {get;set;}
}

public partial class ResumeInfo : IResumeInfo
{

}
```

Then lets say you want a single DTO object:

```
public class DTOUserAndResume
{

       public int id {get;set;}
       public string Name {get;set;} 

       string PlaceOfEmployment {get;set;}
       DateTime StartOfEmployment {get;set;}
       DateTime? EndOfEmployment {get;set;}

   public DTOUserAndResume(IDbOjbect source, IResumeInfo resumeInfo)
   {
      Id = source.Id;
      Name = source.name;

      PlaceOfEmployment = resumeInfo.PlaceOfEmployment;
      StartOfEmployment = resumeInfo.StartOfEmployment ;
      EndOfEmployment = resumeInfo.EndOfEmployment ;

   }
}
```

Now on B? I think you said you have resume data, but not on C?

you implement the IResumeInfo on both, but on B, you just get whatever data is there, but on C that has no data? NullOjbect Pattern.

Implement the interfacce, but make it return nothing.

So PlaceOfEmployment is always "" or Null.
Start data is always 1900-01-01 00:00:00 or whatever you want "nothing" to be on a not nullable object, and null on the end of employment.

So you simply claim that the data is the equavilant of a none-existing data set, because, it doesn't have a dataset to provide.

But you dont need to make a new DTO, you can just update the constructor on CDTO, it will also work fine. It might just get a bit confusing in regards to naming and stuff.

This should result in a call that looks like:

```
C = a.C.Select(cdto => new CDTO{cdto, cdto.ResumeInfo}).ToList();
```

Comment: and if implemented by my method?

Comment: C = a.C.Select(cdto => new CDTO{ Id = cdto.Id, Name = cdto.Name}).ToList(),

Converted to:

C = a.C.Select(cdto => new CDTO(cdto) ).ToList();

Provided C implements IDbOjbect
And CDTO accepts IDbOjbect as a parameter on its constructor.

Thought that was fairly obvious?

Comment: Use the keyword "partial" for the interface implementation, on the class, so you only have the interface implementations in the partial class, that makes it easier to manage.

Comment: Please. Re-read my answer, I have updated it.

(I am assuming that the int definition for Name is a type, and is meant to be string?)

Comment: Select from entity C work good, because entity A treats it as one to many. But how to get data from entity B in the same query? It has the opposite many to one relationship.

Comment: Do you need to list all fields of entities B and C in the interface? Because in the project they are different for me.

Comment: Well, if based on a real model, then I have the essence of Resume, Personal data, Education. I would like to receive a list of resumes, which will contain personal data and information about education. that is, I have a resume as a resulting entity, it contains a foreign key to the personal data table and contains a list of entities. That is, there is a one-to-many relationship, but it is directed to different entities in different ways. I hope I explained clearly

Comment: Then likely your DTO will not be a CDTO will it? 
Then you would need either to allow multiple Interfaces to be provided on the constructor, (one for the base info, ie IDbOjbect) and an interface for the resume data, 

and then in your select, you would need to use the Resume data Interface as an input parameter as well. 

so it would look like: 

C.Select(cdto => new CDTO(cdto, cdto.ResumeInfo) ).ToList(); 

Where ResumeInfo Ojbect would Implement the interface for ResumeInfo.
does that make sense to you?

Comment: Check my answer again, I have updated it with more examples.

Comment: Thx again)I would like format json : [resume : {id: 1, Create: 'today'}, person : {id:1 , name:'max', age:24},education:{id:1,grade:'master',speciality:'IT'}; 
resume : {id: 2, Create: 'today'}, person : {id:1 , name:'max', age:24},education:{id:2,grade:'low',speciality:'IT'}]

Without interfaces i can make it? Only linq ? I dont know how i can get person data , becasuse when i make Select(resume=>new ResumeDTo{}). In entity resumedto i have not public List<Person>, i have public List<Education>. But i can make resume.Person because in Resume entity i have, Person_FK

Comment: Without interfaces, you would need to make an overloaded constructor for each source object, and on each DTO object you create. 

I would not recommend that.